# Adding DropDownList with remote data to Kendo Scheduler popup modal

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I am trying to add a kendo dropdown with remote data (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource) to the kendo scheduler - Here is a code sample in their dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/ebeMo I have been working on getting this working for a week and am completely baffled. I really need to get this working for my job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do couple of things to achieve that:

1. Create a custom template

   `<div id="scheduler"></div>
    <script id="customEditorTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
       <input id="dropdownlist" />
    </script>`
2. Configure custom template in editable section
3. Attach the dropdownlist component in edit section

   `<script>
       $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
       date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
       dataSource: [
       {
           start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
           end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
           title: "Breakfast"
       }
       ],
       editable: {
                   template: $("#customEditorTemplate").html() 
               },
       edit: function (e) {

       var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
               transport: {
                       read: {
                       url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
                       dataType: "jsonp"
                       }
                       }
           });
       $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
           dataSource: dataSource,
           dataTextField: "ProductName",
           dataValueField: "ProductID"
       });
       }
   });
   </script>`

Sample code: http://dojo.telerik.com/ETilE

Hope that helps.